# will pagination - passing in an array variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I have a very specific list of items I'd like to paginate.

Up to now, I've been doing

```
@company = Company.paginate( :page => params[:page], 
                               :conditions => ["activated=1... etc..."],
                               :per_page => 6,
                               :order => order_by)
```

But I'd like to create my own array @company that wouldn't be possible to retrieve through a single query.. and then paginate that. How can I pass the raw array to will_paginate?

Thank you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When loaded, will_paginate extends all arrays with the `paginate` method:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :014 > [].respond_to?(:paginate)
=> true
```

You can just create your array instance however you want and call `paginate` on it.

Comment: so do you mean... say I have a variable @companies.. then I just call @company.paginate(:page => page, :per_page => 6)? i will try this!

Answer (score 1):

Call the `paginate` method on the array.

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]

a.paginate(:page => 1, :per_page => 2)
=> [1,2]    

a.paginate(:page => 2, :per_page => 2)
=> [3,4]    

a.paginate(:page => 3, :per_page => 2)
=> [5]
```

**Reference**: The `Array` [extension](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/blob/master/lib/will_paginate/collection.rb#L40) in the `will_paginate` gem source.